# error no 10061 in django when sending mail

Tags: python, html, django, gmail, sendmail

I already use 10061 server. My code is like,

setting.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

views.py:

```
def trying(request):
    message = request.POST.get('message', '')

    if  message:
        try:
            send_mail("Testing", message, "s.tanna1992@gmail.com",['s.tanna1992@gmail.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponse('Send Successfully...1')
    else:
        # In reality we'd use a form class
        # to get proper validation errors.
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

Which setting should I configure without firewall? Is it neccessary to define port? If it is, then where should I define?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `settings.py` file, are you also defining things like `EMAIL_HOST`, `EMAIL_PORT`, etc?

[See the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#smtp-backend) for the various settings you can use.